# python django subtract timedelta object from datetime object?

Tags: django, python-datetime

A python/django beginner's question:

I have a datetime object (drive_date), a time object (start_time)  and a timedelta object (when_to_notify).

I first do this:

```
d = datetime.combine(l.drive_date, l.start_time)
```

I would then like to subtract the "when_to_notify" timedelta object from d to get a notification date and time.  However, django doesn't like this.  It tells me: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'

How can I subtract the time in the timedelta object from a datetime object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*moved from comment section*]

`datetime.combine` returns a `datetime` from which a `datetime.timedelta` can be subtracted. From the exception it seems you are trying to subtract a `datetime.timedelta` from a time object instead of a `datetime` object. Can you recheck?